# How to add extra checks during login (Rails + Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Ruby On Rails 3.x application using device.

My goal is to add a Yubikey input field to the login screen.

I have generated the views, adjusted the screen (i.e. the extra field shows up) and updated the routes as follows:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions=>"sessions", :registrations => "registrations" }, :path => "users", :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
```

Not to forget, I created a session controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    begin
      if do_some_other_checks
        super
      else
        build_resource
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        flash[:alert] = "Login error"
        render :new
      end
    rescue => e
        build_resource
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        flash[:alert] = "Login error"
        render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't quite work, it gets called after Devise has the user logged on, i.e. even if the additional check fails, the user still gets logged in.

Comment: I Know this isn't exactly what you need but have you looked at the devise two factor plugin? https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication It might be worth reading his source to make sure you're not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this in your user model by adding in the following, no need to create any devise controllers or change default routes ...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 # check to see if a user is active or not and deny login if not
 def active_for_authentication?
   super && do_some_other_checks
 end

end
```

Comment: What if you need to use parameters sent by the user?